# Disabling the Recycle Bin in Wine

Tags: wine, delete

I use Wine to run one program.  That program has the unfortunate tendency to create large numbers of temporary files, all of which it deletes to the Windows recycle bin.  Wine implements that by deleting them to my Cinnamon trash, which happens to be on a different physical device.  This is slow, wastes space, and makes it impossible to find anything in the Cinnamon trash on the rare occasions that I want to.

How can I configure Wine to disable its recycle bin, or failing that, to use a different recycle bin for this one program?  I've tried

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\BitBucket]
"NukeOnDelete"=dword:00000001
```

and

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"NoRecycleFiles"=dword:00000001
```

as suggested by https://superuser.com/questions/1616394/how-to-use-registry-to-disable-recycle-bin-for-all-users-on-all-drives-and-disp but that had no apparent effect.

I **do not** want to disable my Cinnamon trash entirely; I just want to disable it for Wine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a wrapper installer to disable the recycle bin in Wine (References [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601191/10477326) [2](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/90103fa07e5c23c7500c7d33e538b0610bf3c27d/dlls/shell32/shlfileop.c#L1335C52-L1335C70) [3](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/90103fa07e5c23c7500c7d33e538b0610bf3c27d/dlls/shell32/recyclebin.c#L91)):

```bash
dst=~/.local/bin/wine
[ -f $dst ] && { echo 'Run only once'; exit 1; }
mkdir -p ~/.local/bin
real_wine="$(which wine)"
"$real_wine" --version | grep -q wine || { echo 'Broken wine'; exit 1; }
contents="$(
  echo '#!/bin/sh'
  echo WINEHOMEDIR=/disablewinetrash XDG_DATA_HOME=/disablewinetrash exec \"$real_wine\" \"\$@\"
)"
echo "$contents" > "$dst"
chmod +x "$dst"
```

Then you can just use the desktop shortcuts or run `wine path_to.exe`. We need to create a wrapper because the two usual solutions don't work. `XDG_DATA_HOME` will break non-wine applications if set in `.profile` or `.bashrc`. Setting `.bashrc` aliases won't work for the desktop shortcuts.